# why float followed by clear

Tags: css, css-float

What does it mean to float left, then clear left. Or float left, then clear right? Can anyone help me understand this. I'm not a CSS guy, but need to understand some of the CSS I'm working with.

```
#elem1{
    float:left;
    clear:left;
}

#elem2{
    float:left;
    clear:right;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you float two elements together, they will align on the same horizontal axis if you don't apply clearing.

By telling a floating element to clear, it clears any floats that come *before* it, then floats itself wherever the designer intends to float it. It will go on a new line, or not, depending on the direction of the clear.

See this [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/xDHr2) for a visualization. The first two `<div>`s don't clear anything, while the last two `<div>`s are set to clear both left and right floats.

Answer (score 3):

`clear` means to position the element *below* any previous floating elements, to "clear the line".

Usually floating elements pile up on the same line like this:

```
--- --- ---
| | | | | |
--- --- ---
```

Making them clear any previous floating elements will make them arrange like this:

```
---
| |
---
---
| |
---
---
| |
---
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a clearer view of why a clear is needed.  http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html